# JBoss HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied - JBWEB000123: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden

Tags: jboss, http-status-code-403, jboss6.x

> JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied
>
> JBWEB000309: type JBWEB000067: Status report
>
> JBWEB000068: message Access is denied
>
> JBWEB000069: description JBWEB000123: Access to the specified resource
>   has been forbidden.
>
> JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1

in PostMan app I Got this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1 - JBWEB000064: Error report</title>
        <style>
            <!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}-->
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>JBWEB000065: HTTP Status 403 - Access is denied</h1>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000309: type</b> JBWEB000067: Status report
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000068: message</b>
            <u>Access is denied</u>
        </p>
        <p>
            <b>JBWEB000069: description</b>
            <u>JBWEB000123: Access to the specified resource has been forbidden.</u>
        </p>
        <HR size="1" noshade="noshade">
        <h3>JBoss Web/7.5.7.Final-redhat-1</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: What are you trying to access? Do you have any security constraints in the web.xml?

Comment: I have 3 web.xml, they are in sandalone\tmp\vfs\temp\tmp8013a1bd5da4f8ec\folder...

Comment: so please show them and the url you are trying to access. 403 means that the authentication was succesful but the use is not allowed to access the resource